# Separate template for dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I need to use a separate template for dashboard. So that 
http://mysite/dashboard loads a completely different template.

So, I have created a template under layouts/dashboard_template.html.erb

My dashboard cotroller

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render template: 'layouts/dashboard_template.html.erb'  

  end
end
```

I have added following routes.rb

```
get 'dashboard', to: 'dashboard#index'
```

but, it loads the template inside application.html.erb! Not sure how to fix it. Hope it is clear. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your dashboard controller use

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  layout :set_layout, only: [:index]

  def index
    # do your stuff
  end

  def set_layout
    "layout_file_name" || 'application'
  end
end
```

this will load your layout if present else main application layout

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed :)